# Appending when using selectAll in d3

Tags: jquery, d3.js, append, selectall

I'm using d3 and I want to append to an element that I'm appending.

```
svg.append('g').attr('foo', 'bar')
    .selectAll('rect').data(data)
    .enter().append('rect')
        .attr('class', function(d) { return 'some-class' })
        .attr('y', 0)
        .attr('height', 42)
        .attr('x', function(d) { return d.x); })
        .attr('width', 9001);
        // hot damn would it be cool if I could just .append a span here...
```

I want to append a span to the elements I'm inserting, but I don't know how.  People say to use appendTo but I don't know how that works with the selectAll, I tried looping over the elements and adding them but that isn't working either an I'm not sure why.

```
svg.append('g').attr('foo', 'bar');
_.each(data, function(d) {
    var rect = $('rect')
        .attr('class', function() { return 'some-class'; })
        .attr('y', 0)
        .attr('height', 42)
        .attr('x', function() { return d.x; })
        .attr('width', 9001)
        .append('<span class="cool-class">Spantastic!</span>');

    svg.append(rect);
});
```

I am not very familiar with this type of thing, I've made a few changes guessing how it should be, but nothing works (d3 contains about the object having no method "indexOf").  Any ideas?  Thanks.

Comment: You should be able to simply add `.append("span")` to the end of your first block of code. That will append a `span` element to each `rect`.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff thank you!  I had been doing it wrong and tried to find the answer on google and it saw people talking about how you couldn't use .append .append because the original object was returned not the new one, and I thought that was my problem.

Comment: Cool, I'll add that as an answer for reference.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to simply add `.append("span")` to the end of your first block of code. That will append a `span` element to each `rect`.